# using "range" in a google app engine template for - loop

Tags: python, django-templates

i've got an appengine project and in my template i want to do something like

```
{% for i in range(0, len(somelist)) %}
  {{ somelist[i] }} {{ otherlist[i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

i've tried using 'forloop.counter' to access list items too, but that didn't work out either. any suggestions?

regards, mux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you might want to do instead is change the data that you're passing in to the template so that somelist and otherlist are zipped together into a single list:

```
combined_list = zip(somelist, otherlist)
...
{% for item in combined_list %}
    {{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is the right idea, although the syntax for list item lookup in Django templates is {{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}

Comment: thank you for the tip! i read that 'zip' can have more than two lists as input, so as long as i match up everything correctly beforehand that's exactly what i was looking for.

thank you!

Comment: You may consider using itertools.izip which returns a generator instead of a complete list.